# Linux command to extend the duration of audio files

Tags: linux, command-line, audio

I have a web application that let's people make sound effects. Sometimes the sound effects are less than 0.55 seconds in length. When this is the case they may fail to play properly in the Chrome browser. I would like to know of a command line audio processing utility that will enable me to pad out the sounds shorter than 0.55s with emptiness to increase the sound duration to be at least 0.55s.

I have looked into Audacity batch processing, but could not figure out how to use it on the command line. I have also looked into using sox, but could not find an option for extending a sound to be a minimum duration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
sox -n silence.wav trim 0.55
```

to generate a 0.55s long file of silence.

Then

```
sox -m -v 1 yourfile.wav silence.wav -t wav outfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a silent 0.55s wav. Then concatenate it with your file. It will have more than 0.55s... so you might want to cut it.

```
sox yourfile.wav silence.wav outfile.wav trim 0 0.55
```

Edit: it seems it can generate silence using -n as filename. So it would look like:

```
sox yourfile.wav -n outfile.wav trim 0 0.55
```

If yourfile.wav has samplerate different than 48000, you need to generate silence at this rate too for concatenation to work:

```
sox yourfile_at_44100.wav -r 44100 -n outfile.wav trim 0 0.55
```

And if you want to do that only with files that actually are shorter than 0.55, you might want to filter them by checking their duration using `soxi`.

Comment: How do I know how much to cut? I don't want to cut any non-silence part of the audio.

Comment: @Daniel X Moore: That's why I wrote about soxi: you need to do this operation only on files which are shorter than .55s. A shell loop with some grep/awk to check condition should do.

Comment: Example please? I think the mixing technique is the simpler way to do it as it works with any file length.

Comment: @Daniel X Moore: yes, now I also think so.

Answer (score 1):

Check [SoX](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SoX) you should be able to accomplish that. Its a Audio-Toolkit (multiplatform). First append enough silence to the end of the sound and then cut out the appropriate part.